# How to prevent spaces and tabs in a text field using validation rule

Tags: validation

How can I prevent spaces and tabs in a string field using a validation rule?

Comment: Do you mean tabs and spaces mixed in with text, or tabs and spaces just on their own?

Comment: mixed e.g. sund ay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with regular expressions. The character class `\s` represents whitespace. A simple regex to search for any whitespace would be `[\s]+` which will match 1 or more whitespace characters.

For more in-depth information on regular expressions I recommend this [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) that is my primary reference.

**Update**

As PeterKnolle pointed out in the comments, the correct regular expression should be `.*\\s+.*`. The dots are needed to match any and all other characters before or after the whitespace.

Comment: This is what I'm trying but it does not work REGEX(myField__c, "[\\s]+")

Comment: Odd. I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Dedo and @MikeChale - It uses [Java regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), so you should be able to do `REGEX(myField__c ,".*\\s+.*")` in a validation rule, I think

Comment: @PeterKnolle Strange, it is not working. Maybe a salesforce bug?

Comment: @PeterKnolle This is it: REGEX(myField__c ,".*\\s+.*"). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do this in a formula field (which can't use `REGEX`) and it's not elegant, but it does work and it should also work for your scenario:

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Field__c, ' ', ''), ' ', '')
```

To use it in a validation rule, you just need to compare the result of this with the original string, if they're different, then the string must contain whitespace.

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Field__c, ' ', ''), ' ', '') != Field__c
```

Note that the second `' '` is actually a tab, it just appears as a space here for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent that this field remains empty - try this formula:

```
ISBLANK(TRIM(MyText__c))
```

Comment: not exactly, I want to make sure there are no spaces in between the characters e.g. "Ononm atopea" should be prevented because it has a space

Comment: I tried contains but it didn't work. Is there any RegEx I can use?